# 0x API Help: Is this bandwith consumption normal for 0x api?

Tags: 0x

thanks for stopping by my question.

I'm implementing a bot that uses the /quote endpoint of 0x API to check some trading prices. The 0x application is dockerized, together with postgreSQL and redis, as per the documentation, and running fine. The bot performs 5 /quote requests every ~2 seconds, on the BSC network.

The problem I'm having is that this is hosted on a cloud server that notified me of excessive bandwith usage. So I used iftop to check just that, and as it turns out, the incoming traffic between my local 0x API and Amazon servers is about 150 MB every 2 minutes.

Before migrating to another service that gives me more bandwith, I'd like to know, is this normal? What is the need to exchange so much data? I think maybe I've misconfigured something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out the lesson is not to use /quote until you're going to actually make a transaction. /price transmits only a few KB in the same span of time that /quote transmits hundreds of MB. I wanted to use quote directly to avoid a second request and lose as little time as possible, but I'm going to bite the bullet, check /price first, and only invoke /quote if the bot has to trade.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch my previous response. Apparently it was just a happy accident. Today it's consuming a CRAZY amount of bandwith, around 2 MB/s, and using the /price endpoint. Running the application locally in my PC yields the same result. What on earth is going on with this app?